# Changing product name for configurable product when being added to cart?

Tags: magento2, after-plugin

**Magento 2.4.6**

I am trying to change the name of a configurable product which is added to the cart. I figured that changing the `getProductName` function in `\vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Configurable.php` does the trick.

Now I am trying to override that with a plugin, which does not work. This is what I have:

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer">
    <plugin name="modify_product_name_cart" type="What\Ever\Plugin\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Configurable" sortOrder="3" disabled="false" />
 </type>
```

**\app\code\What\Ever\Plugin\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Configurable.php**

```
namespace What\Ever\Plugin\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer;

class Configurable {
    public function afterGetProductName(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item, $result) {
    
        return __('Product Sample') . ' ' . $item->getProduct()->getName();
    
    }   
}
```

This is not working though, it never reaches the code. So I need to know why the code is not reached and if it was reached, if it is the correct way to change the product name?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you do not seen the changes to miniCart pop/dropdown?

Comment: is change related to JavaScript you need to override minicart.js

Comment: When I add the changes to Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Configurable.php directly, it works and I see the changes in the mini cart. To make it the propber way, I wanted to create a plugin, which does not work though. I think no JS has to be involved here...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It would be useful for something I'm working on.